# Git: How to include working tree status in git log --pretty=format...?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-cdt

I'm using the following command in an Eclipse CDT pre-build step, to generate a header file containing my current short Git hash as a string macro:

```
git log --pretty=format:'#define GIT_HASH_STRING "%h"' -n 1 > ../Inc/gitcommit.h
```

Works great, but it doesn't indicate the status of the working tree. Like when running `git submodule status`, if there are working tree changes, I'd like it to spit out something like

```
a289542-dirty
```

Is this possible? I checked the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) for git-log formats, but didn't see anything that looked pertinent.

Context: The `GIT_HASH_STRING` macro is displayed when issuing a `version` command via the CLI of an embedded device. If I can include a `-dirty` flag in the string, it can serve as a warning that the device is running an unreleased version of firmware that doesn't align with a specific commit.

Comment: So this entire question actually belies some shortsightedness on my part... I followed @torek's suggestion below, and got it working by replacing the $() with backticks (Eclipse tried to substitute a non-existing environment variable). HOWEVER, with this arrangement it's impossible *not* to have the -dirty flag attached, since each post-commit build changes the working directory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git log` command does not inspect the work-tree, so it cannot do this.

There are many commands that *do* inspect the work-tree.  One simple one is `git describe`:

```
git describe --always --dirty
```

will print out a string that will end with `-dirty` if the work-tree or the index is modified with respect to the current commit (i.e., in the same situations where `git status` would say something is staged for commit or not staged for commit).

If you want to check submodules as well, you will need more.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great step. Now, to figure out how to embed the output into a preformatted string to redirect into the header file. Guessing some sed wizardry?

Comment: Most people who do this sort of thing run: `printf '#define ... "%s"\n' $(git describe ...flags...) > file.h`